# Corona SDK tables

Tags: lua, iteration, coronasdk, lua-table

```
balls = {}
createBall()

function checkLocation()
    for i,v in pairs(balls) do --loops through all the balls
        if v.x>320 or v.x<-50 or v.y<-30 then --Removes balls outside of the screen
            v:removeSelf()
            balls[i]=nil
            print "gone"
        end 
    end
end

function shoot(x, y)
    if balls[#balls].inAir==false then --Checks if the last made ball is already shot
        balls[#balls]:setLinearVelocity(-x,-y) --sets the velocity for the last made ball
        balls[#balls].inAir=true; -- is shot
    end
    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, createBall ) -- Creates a new ball after 1 second
end

function createBall()
    boll = {};
    boll = display.newCircle( 160, 400, 20 )
    boll.x, boll.y = 160, 400
    boll:setFillColor(255,0,0)
    physics.addBody( boll, { density=1.0, friction=0.3, bounce=0.3, radius=25} )
    boll:setLinearVelocity(0,0)
    boll.inAir=false
    balls[#balls+1] = boll; -- adds the new ball to the balls table
    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, shoot ) -- shoots the ball after 1 second
end
```

My program is working for 3 balls. They are created, shot, and deleted, but it cannot shoot the 4th ball. The program works if I delete the whole `checkLocation` function, but I want to delete the balls. What am I doing wrong? Maybe something with the `balls[#balls]` is wrong, but for me it should mean that it selects the last made ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, if your `balls` table is an array-like table, or you want to iterate over the array part only, you're better off using [`ipairs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) or a standard [`for i`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.5) loop instead. [`pairs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-pairs) iterates over all indices of a table, including non-numeric ones such as string keys.

Not to mention that `pairs` (*via* [`next`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-next)) also iterates in an undefined order, whereas `ipairs` will always iterate in a predictable fashion from `1` to the first integer key absent from the table. Note that if you're using a standard `for i` loop with the length operator [`#t`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.6), it can be a little different if your table is not sequential.

> Unless a __len metamethod is given, the length of a table t is only defined if the table is a sequence, that is, the set of its positive numeric keys is equal to {1..n} for some integer n. In that case, n is its length.

---

**Secondly**, setting numeric indices of an array-like table will leave your table with *holes*.

```
local t = {1, 2, 3}
t[2] = nil
-- t is {1, nil, 3}, not {1, 3} as one might expect.
```

You will need to use [`table.remove`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.remove) if you want to preserve the sequential consistency of your table.

```
local t = {1, 2, 3}
table.remove(t, 2)
-- t is {1, 3}
```

---

**Last but not least** is the less obvious and less intuitive flaw in your approach to removing elements.

```
local t = {2, 3, 5, 2, 1}
for i=1, #t do
    if t[i] % 2 == 1 then  -- If value is odd,
        table.remove(t, i) -- remove it.
    end
end
-- t is {2, 3, 2}, but that can't be right.
```

You're removing elements from an array as you iterate over them in a forward fashion. This will inevitably lead to you skipping every element after the one removed, possibly to the point where you iterate over the outside of the array.

If you want to remove elements from an array as you iterate over it, then you must do it *backwards*. If for some reason you cannot iterate backwards over the array, then you will have to save a list of indices to remove later and iterate over those backwards.

At this point, you might be asking, "Why *backwards?*" Simply put, it is because the loop does not update the length or keep the iterator the same as the table's size decreases which causes the skipping. If you go backwards, then you're preserving the structure in which the iteration is processed. The length does not need to be updated since it is now the starting value instead of the end condition. The iterator does not need to be "held back" or kept from stepping either, since there will always be more elements in front of it, due to it going backwards.

```
local t = {2, 3, 5, 2, 1}
for i=#t, 1, -1 do -- Start at the end and go backwards.
    if t[i] % 2 == 1 then
        table.remove(t, i)
    end
end
-- t is {2, 2}, as expected.
```

---

In conclusion, (*the **tl;dr** version*)

- Use `ipairs` instead of `pairs` for arrays, if you prefer using iterators vs. a `for i` loop.
- Use `table.remove` to preserve sequentiality of an array.
- Use backwards `for i` loops when removing elements from arrays.

Comment: The best answer around, regarding lua tables. Congratulations. It help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of balls, you can't do `balls[i]=nil` you have to do `table.remove(balls, i)` or your array will have a nil value in the middle of it and will stop working properly, using table.remove removes an item and shifts the remaining items.

Comment: This answer is only partially correct. You did not mention how removing elements from a table while traversing it with `pairs` will lead to skipping.

Comment: @RyanStein Of course what you are writing is just wrong, see the [Lua reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-next): *The behavior of next is undefined if, during the traversal, you assign any value to a non-existent field in the table. You may however modify existing fields. In particular, you may clear existing fields. *

Comment: You may clear existing fields. Clear is not the same as remove in the context of a sequence/array. Please try this small demo, and you will see that one of the `5`s will not be removed, hence it is skipped. `t = {2, 3, 5, 5, 2, 1};for k,v in pairs(t) do if v % 2 == 1 then table.remove(t,k) end end;print(table.concat(t, ','))`